# Is it possible to find out if two accounts came from a single wallet?

Tags: metamask, wallets

You can create as many as accounts you wanted to in metamask. Although it is just an interface.

My question is, suppose, if I create an ACCOUNT 1, and an ACCOUNT 2 in a single wallet, is it possible find that these two accounts are owned by one person and came from one wallet?

A while ago, when I was receiving eth from ropsten faucet(I forgot which faucet), I remember when I tried to use second account from the same wallet, it denied with the reason, an user can only accept test ETH once per day.

Are they just keeping track of IP address and barring them from taking the test ETH if they received eth in last 24 hours? Or is there a way to find out the origin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For an external viewer all of these accounts only seem as a generic public address. You can't make the connection that these accounts are managed by the same wallet.

On websites that provide ethers for testing they do count on IPs, Website user and social network accounts to limit the amount of test ether you can get.

Also, if a website has access to all of the accounts in your Metamask wallet it can make the connection, Also, it can make the connection between an IP and an address.

Answer (score 1):

Testnet faucets keep track of IP addresses to detect malicious users. In addition, they also keep track of session ID in the browser as more sophisticated users can use VPN or similar service to hide their activity.